# Why can't I install Sitecore.Kernel v9.1.1 via Nuget?

Tags: installation, nuget, visual-studio

I am upgrading an old VS project that was built using Sitecore 7.2.  I have changed the target .NET Framework to 4.7.1.  Now I am trying to install Sitecore.Kernel v9.1.1 via Nuget.  However when I try to do that I get the following error:

> Could not install package
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions 2.1.1'. You are
>   trying to install this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1', but the package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework.

I have also attempted to install the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions` package separately but I get the same error.  No matter what I do I can't install `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions`.  What's really strange is that if I create a brand new solution that targets .NET 4.7.1 I can install if fine.  So there must be something strange in my existing project/solution that is preventing me from installing `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions 2.1.1`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is all projects in the Solution has the target framework set to 4.7.1?

Comment: Yes all projects target .NET Framework 4.7.1

Comment: Can you remove all the references and then start by adding the different nugets

Comment: Assuming you're on a recent nuget, close VS and try running `nuget.exe locals -clear all`. Then try installing again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was to update Visual Studio from 15.0 to 15.9.  Once I did that then the installation from Nuget worked. Who would have guessed.  :)